# My colleague doesn't understand things he works with. What to do?

Tags: project-management

I've spent 3 days debugging one very obscure bug in a library made by my colleague, this bug happens very infrequently. After all I found that this bug happens due to cross-thread access to an object without any lock. Actually this is not a first bug of this kind, there were similar bugs before. He just runs his unit tests, and if something fails puts somewhere a lock. And if nothing fails, ughm, then his code is perfect. It seems he has no idea about threading safety. I'm 100% sure there are many similar bugs that just haven't surfaced yet. It seems PM doesn't understand threading stuff too.
The problem is, he works much more time in the company than I do. Anyway, I can't just say "this guy is incompetent in this area", because this always shows you as a "bad team player", etc.
Any ideas, what I can do?

Comment: What country is this?

Comment: It's international company.

Comment: If it's really a big issue and you are 100% certain that your colleague is making a mistake, first thing is to politely point it out in such a way that he isn't threatened. The second thing is, if your colleague doesn't listen, is just to point out the potential damages in cash. That's what all managers listen to, and very carefully at that. Having a threading problem such as you described is potentially very harmful, and unless you're 100% certain in your statements, go forward with them.

Comment: Likely belongs on the [Project Management](http://pm.stackexchange.com) SE site.

Comment: The Project Management SE site does not have a "Multithreading" tag, which this question should have.

Comment: If the execution environment allows a stack trace or a memory dump to be captured at the point of crash, then a single such evidence should be sufficient to build a case for one or more possible defects in the code. If such capture is not possible, then the code should be instrumented (manually, by adding trace logging, or automatically) to print out the program's internal states at high frequency. Mind you, it could be a defect in the library, or a defect in the code that calls the library, or both. Finally, once the smoking gun is found, have a joint code review with the library writer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Convince PM that to avoid such bugs, the know-how of the team about threading stuff should be improved, and tell them that you are willing to organize something like a workshop or a presentation about it. Don't make it a personal thing between you and your colleague.

Comment: I'm afraid this won't be welcome by that guy, because he thinks he _is_ professional in this area (and can teach everyone himself). But I can try.

Comment: Ah yes, and one big problem - English is not my native language, I speak not very well.

Comment: If both your colleague and PM have limited knozledge of threading, and thread safety, then training is definitely the best approach. It's not one guy's incompetence - it's the team's competence that is the problem.

Comment: A workshop is something where all of you can throw in their knowledge, and all of you should learn something from it. If your colleague thinks he knows something about threading, perhaps you can learn some things from him, too.

Answer (score 8):

Write a unit test that shows the bug and ask him to fix it.

Comment: He already aware of this bug. He just can't find the reason.

Comment: Didn't you found the reason in the three day debug session?  Or do I read your question incorrectly?

Comment: I found it. But I can't do his job all time. I have my own tasks to do.

Comment: How will you prove without a doubt that this is not _your_ task?

Comment: Oh really? Because this library is not _my_ project.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Are you sure that it is possible to write a unit test that in every run will show a bug due to a race condition without modifying the code of the class under test?

Comment: @scarfridge, actually, it's completely impossible. Race conditions always are unpredictable. But the test can reproduce it after some hours of repetitions and billions of runs ^_^

Comment: @scarfridge Depends on the platform.  For Java you can use byte code instrumentation or Aspect oriented programming to insert a wait exactly where the problem is, (or use JVMTI to control the execution).  It is possible to do!

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen, how wait is supposed to help reproduce unsynchronized memory access?

Comment: You have a situation where multiple threads are executed in a very special sequence.  You need to reproduce that execution sequence in your test, and emulate the external task switching.  The simplest way to do this is to tell the runtime that other threads can execute, e.g. with a wait.  If you need better control, open a separate question.

Comment: @tika, "the library is not _my_ project".  Your problem is that it is your word against your colleagues that the bug is in _his_ code and not _yours_.  Remember, he has tests in place saying his code is correct...

Comment: It's not only matter of sequence. Many other factors are involved - which cores execute code, when GC occurs and how it moves objects, how changes are propagated from one core's cache to another, etc.

Comment: Can you describe the exact steps needed to trigger the bug so it can be reproduced?

Comment: Actually it's just a set of method calls repeated billions of times. But this doesn't matter much. The real reason is access to a dictionary object from 2 threads without lock (i.e. without memory barriers). Thread A creates it, thread B reads it.

Comment: Tika I understand that the _reason_ is the missing lock.  The question was, can you describe the actual instructions executed and in what order to actually _trigger_ the bug?  If not, the bug might still be in your code.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen - No test in the world can say that a code is correct, only that it is incorrect.

Comment: @mouviciel I am aware of that.  Please read the section where Tika refers to the library author pointing to all his tests passing.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen - Actually my argument is not directed to you but to the library author.

Comment: @mouviciel then perhaps you should direct the comment to @tika?

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen, to find exact instructions to trigger this bug, it's necessary to go to assembly language level, or even lower.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen - can any of the information in these comments be incorporated in the answer? There are a lot and are candidate for deletion.

Comment: @ChrisF I believe the comment thread prove that the question is too localized and should be deleted.

Answer (score 4):

- It's a senior developer's job to review his code and suggest improvements.
- You are not there to check after his work, I would personally hate if somebody was re-checking all my changes to see if anything broke
- If he doesn't accept your advise, then it's PM's job to fix the communication issue.
- Threading issue in a unit test makes me wonder whether this test is actually a unit test, rather than integration or component test.

Comment: I get your idea. Obey your command.

Comment: What does it matter if a test showing an issue is called "unit test" or "integration test"? The whole situation remains the same.

Comment: My concern is that his colleague might not know the difference between the unit and component test, therefore further training might be required to address this issue.

Comment: @CodeRush - I take it you do not believe in peer review?  What would it take for you to actually appreciate that somebody else was rechecking your code (as opposed to just crash in production)?

Comment: I get the idea, but I haven't seen it working effectively in my previous jobs. I think that reviews by a senior developer is a better feedback mechanism.

Comment: I think the difference is that if your company has peer reviews, then it's part of the process to have everyone's code checked by someone else - it's a friendly, cover-our-backs thing where everyone is helping everyone else to make sure no bugs sneak through. On the other hand, if one developer is continually going over your code (and just yours) when it's not their job to do so, it comes across as a sneaky I-don't-trust-you-to-not-break-the-code kind of thing, which is much less pleasant.

Answer (score -5):

I think your company should not be using multithreading.

After doing a massively multithreaded project, I found two techniques were critical to making things work.  **First**, the code had to be written right.  Every field had to be manually checked to make sure it was declared properly and properly synchronized whereever referenced.  (Warning:  I am simplifying things a bit here to keep my answer short--or at any rate, shorter.)  **Second**, the code had to be tested by running it flat out on single *and* multicore machines--many minutes using 100% of each core.  (And if it only uses 2% of each core, as it often did for me, that's a bug too.)

You might be able to manage this, but your organization can't.  Even if they understood the problem, which they don't, they don't have the expertise.

Most languages provide ways to avoid this.  If you have a socket reader, which usually has its own thread, have it get the info to the main thread as quickly and simply as possible.  Better yet, look for system classes/functions that will handle the thread-part of the reading for you.  Use a queue that runs "events" one after the other, like most GUI API's do.  (Use the GUI API's event queue itself, for that matter.)  If you need parallel processing, you can probably find some kind of "worker thread" that will let you keep data/fields in a single thread, handling all transfers for you.

Emphasise to all the dangers of multithreading.  (Scary stories:  My favorite bug involved a couple of lines like:  `int i = 5; i = i * i;`, which resulted in `i` having a value of 35.  One I saw a lot was: `if (thing != null)  thing.reset();` throwing a null pointer exception.)  I think your only hope is making them understand they're stepping into a whole, new, strange world, and that maybe they should take one big step back.

I'm not real sure how multithreading *should* be handled.  If the job can be given to one person, and everything they do thrown away if they fail, fine.  But a team is only going to be as strong as its weakest member, and even a good programmer will have trouble with full-blown multithreading.  I hope the language people will find a way to make it safe.  I have seen some helpful software out there.  But I think it best to avoid multithreading unless execution time is critical *and* a good programmer or a *proven* team is available.

Comment: You have no idea what company it is, or what they're doing, so the comment *"You might be able to manage this, but your organization can't"* is a bit unfounded - for all you know, tika could work at Microsoft. Whoever they are, multithreading may well be the best way to solve their problem; there are plenty of situations where it fits. And putting all that aside, the question isn't about multithreading, it's about handling a colleague who's causing problems due to a lack of expertise.

Comment: @anaximander: Multithreading produces bugs that are very hard to reproduce and so very hard to track down.  To produce usable, fixable MT software, you will need, at a minimum, to have programmers and management that are aware of the dangers.  Tika's organization plainly _could not_ handle this.  I've seen testing/QA people force programmers to write sound code by testing heavily and demanding fixes for every bug.  That doesn't work with MT.  If the colleague lacks ability, interest, and motivation, handle him by keeping him away from MT.

Comment: @anaximander:  You must have had better experiences with Microsoft than I've had.  Though to be fair, I've never seen anything that looked like a mutlithreading bug from them.  ....And thanks for the comment.

Comment: Regardless, when the question is "how do I handle a colleague who lacks expertise?", I don't think "your company is building software wrong" is a valid answer. In any organisation, no matter how vast and knowledgeable, there will always be those with gaps in their knowledge. Without knowing the who organisation is or what the software is doing, I don't think you can reliably make the judgement that the company doesn't know what they're doing, or that their problem can be solved without multithreading.